Issue closing Dropdownmenu in Jetpack Compose
I have a Dropdownmenu, opened from an action icon in a TopAppBar in a Scaffold and have an issue with the "close by tap outside" functionality. Because the app is attempting to run in immersive mode, I have used PopupProperties to turn off focus to prevent the system action bars appearing! With this arrangement I get the issue described below.
If I tap outside the Dropdownmenu, it will close but the item on screen that I have tapped also receives the tap and reacts accordingly. With this kind of "tap outside" functionality, the menu should be closed and the tap "consumed" and not passed through to other entities? With Focus set on, I get the expected behaviour but the system bar pops up when the menu opens.

Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
